# Does GPGPU fall under the distributed and/or shared memory computing paradigm(s)?

Tags: gpu, shared-memory, gpgpu, distributed-system

I've seen some mixed resources on this question. Most resources that I've seen suggest that GPU parallel computing fall under shared memory because obviously the cores on a local GPU have access to each other's memory.

When can a GPU be used in a distributed manner? When you have GPUs across distributed systems where each local GPU does its own processing and then there's some communication between the distributed systems?

Comment: A GPU can serve multiple processes which don't see each others private memory, makes a GPU capable of indirectly working as "distributed" too. Also by "unified memory" support, GPUs can be "shared distributed" because one application can see both GPUs memory areas as a single buffer area.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik What is the idea behind making memory private for processes on the same GPU? If you have multiple GPU's working on multiple tasks for the same program, they would, by default be working in a distributed setting? (since each GPU will not have access to the other's memory?)

Comment: @lamanon I think its mainly virtualization, isolation, optimization so that drivers can optimize them separately, otherwise some application would consume all resources and others wouldn't have enough time to work on it.(in shared cloud instance for example). If two GPUs can't join into same work, then they'd be distributed but if they can somehow (either by their implicit unified memory or by application's explicit load balancing), then "shared" is also added. Because resources are shared now? GPUs can also connect to other nodes using special connections "ip over infiniband" by GPUdirect etc

Comment: Even if you write some CUDA warp-level codes that makes 1 cuda thread to control its 3 neighbor cuda threads to distribute them data from main memory, have them synchronized, then get their results and push to main memory, it should also be a kind of distributed computing from point of view of that controller cuda thread. However I'm not sure if having a "TCP/IP/IB" connection is a must to mark it as "distributed" officially.